# Canvas simple game DRY refactoring

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, prototype

I'm a daily reader of this site but not very often a writer. Since I'm learning JavaScript for few weeks, I made a little canvas/JS crossing-game game based on few objects and I'm trying to improve it. The game is very simple: you can see the full code and play here: https://jsfiddle.net/vhrqb5xb/1/
and here : http://codepen.io/Pggo/pen/NGyQXK

```
    // The car variable 
    var Car = {}

    // How I create it
    var resetCar = function () {

      Car.x = 300 + (Math.random() * (canvas.width-600));
      Car.y = -10

    };


    // How it's drawn
    function drawCar(){

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(Car.x,Car.y,32,32);
      ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
      ctx.fill();
      Car.y += Math.random() * 80

      if (Car.y > canvas.height){
        resetCar();
      };

    }


    // How game is reseit if player touch car
    function drawTouchCar(){

    // Evaluate coordonates of both objects, reset of touch
    if (
      player.x <= (Car.x + 32)
      && Car.x <= (player.x + 10)
      && player.y <= (Car.y + 30) &&
      Car.y <= (player.y + 10)
      ){
    ++numberOfDeaths; // +1 Die
    resetPlayer();
    }
    // if player pass arival line
    if(player.x > (canvas.width - 170 )){
      resetPlayer();
    ++numberOfWins; // +1 Win
    }
    }
```

Now, the trick I use is that I have a fast car speed to render it so fast that it seems like there are more than one, but my game only relies on one object, the car. I would like to be able to add more car dynamically (not by creating myself a car2 object). I have made researches and several tries in order to use a prototype to create my objects, I'm able to create more objects easily but my problem is that I cannot access their x and y attributes to use it my collision function.

So, here comes the question, how shall I process to implement a prototype for the actual object car that can create dynamically new car objects and return their x and y property so I can re-use it in my collision function. Actually I'm just here to understand cause I'm stuck but I'm not looking for a working solution out of the box.

Thank in advance for your responses, have a good

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to create an Object. Each method has its advantages and disadvantages.

The quickest way is add hoc using an object factory to create unnamed objects as needed. This method creates the fastest code.

```
var drawCar = function () { // function to draw a car;
    ctx.beginPath();
    // "this" is the car object and should be bound to a car object
    ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, 32, 32);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fill();
    // do your test to see if car is over the line
    // and call
    this.reset(); // to reset the car
}

var resetCar = function () {
    // car reset function TODO add your reset code
}

var carFactory = function () { // creates add hoc unnamed car objects
    var car = {}; // create a new object;
    car.x = 0; // give it properties
    car.y = 0;
    // add the reset function to the car and bind it to the new car
    car.reset = resetCar.bind(car);
    car.draw = drawCar.bind(car); // same for draw
    car.reset(); // reset the car ready to go;
    return car; // return the new car
}

var testCar = function (car) { // function to test if car hits player
    if (
        player.x <= (car.x + 32) // access the car position by its x and y properties
         && car.x <= (player.x + 10)
         && player.y <= (car.y + 30) &&
        car.y <= (player.y + 10)) {
        ++numberOfDeaths; // +1 Die
        resetPlayer();
    }
}

var car1 = carFactory(); // create a new car
var car2 = carFactory(); // and another;

var mainLoop() { // called once every frame
    car1.draw();
    car2.draw();
    testCar(car1);
    testCar(car2);
    // TODO the other stuff
}
```

Next is the formal method, it is slightly slower because there is more stuff happening under the hood (so to speak)

```
function Car() {
    // "this" is bound automatic to the car object with the call new Car()
    // the car also is a named type in Javascript
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.reset(); // reset the new car

    // "this" is returned here automatically like in the factory but in this 
    // case you dont have to type it in 
}

// add draw to the car prototype
Car.prototype.draw = function () { // function to draw a car;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, 32, 32);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fill();
    // this.reset(); // to reset the car
}

// add reset to the car prototype
Car.prototype.reset = function () {
    // car reset function TODO add your reset code }
}

var testCar = function (car) { // function to test if car hits player
    if (
        player.x <= (car.x + 32) // access the car position by its x and y properties
         && car.x <= (player.x + 10)
         && player.y <= (car.y + 30) &&
        car.y <= (player.y + 10)) {
        ++numberOfDeaths; // +1 Die
        resetPlayer();
    }
}
var car1 = new Car(); // create a new car
var car2 = new Car(); // and another;


var mainLoop() { // called once every frame
    car1.draw();
    car2.draw();
    testCar(car1);
    testCar(car2);
}
```

You could also use `class` to create cars in ECMAScript 6. You can also declare all the prototypes inside the Car function allowing you to use closure to add hidden properties. It is slightly slower to create a new car, but slightly quicker to run the new car..

If you want absolute control you use the Object methods directly allowing you to create properties that have options for writable, enumerable, configurable, you can create getters and setters, you can freeze objects and a whole heap more. Personally I leave that stuff up to the gurus.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Totally helps, If you are interested to see what I came up with before I discovered your answer here is a link to the actual version:
http://codepen.io/Pggo/pen/NGyQXK
Thanks your very much for your time and helpful answer, I'll take time to study this carefully in the next hours but it seems like full of good ideas.